# Simple question about C# if else statement

Tags: c#

Iam doing a simple website and when i press button, i should see weight in label.. i see but if text.maxlenght > 6, i should see ERROR message in same label but repeat see weight in label. How can i solve this problem?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double sayi1, sayi2, sayi3, hesap, sonuc;

    sayi1 = Convert.ToDouble(Tb1.Text);
    sayi2 = Convert.ToDouble(Tb2.Text);
    sayi3 = Convert.ToDouble(Tb3.Text);

    if (Tb1.MaxLength > 6 || Tb2.MaxLength > 6)
    {
        lbl1.Text = "ERROR.";

    }
    else
    {
        hesap = (((sayi1 - ((sayi1 - sayi2) / 2)) * ((sayi1 - sayi2) / 2)) / 40);
        sonuc = (hesap * sayi3) / 100;
        lbl1.Text = sonuc.ToString() + "kg";
    }


}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "C#.net". There's only "C#".

Comment: There is no Dana, only Zool...  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want

```
Tb1.Text.Length > 6
```

Rather than

```
Tb1.MaxLength > 6
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but are you trying to get the length of the contents in the textbox?

In that case you would say:

```
Tb1.Text.Length > 6
```

Not

```
Tb1.MaxLength > 6
```

MaxLength like you are using is a property of the textbox, but is not based on the contents of the input field.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with the reference to Tb1.MaxLength.  This property is a validation property that prevents the user from entering text longer than that value.

If you set the MaxLength attribute in the textbox then the user will never be able to enter more than 6 characters.

If you want an error, then check the length of the text, with

Tb1.Text.Length > 6

you could also use the double.tryparse function just in case someone doesn't enter a numerical value in the text box (but then you could achieve the same end with a validator).

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to store that label in a session or viewstate variable, and the set it again insider your if statement:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { double sayi1, sayi2, sayi3, hesap, sonuc;

    sayi1 = Convert.ToDouble(Tb1.Text);
    sayi2 = Convert.ToDouble(Tb2.Text);
    sayi3 = Convert.ToDouble(Tb3.Text);

    if (Tb1.Text.Length > 6 || Tb2.Text.Length > 6)
    {
        lbl1.Text = "ERROR.";
        if (session["currentTb1"] != null && session["currentTb2"] != null){
             Tb1.Text = session["currentTb1"].toString();
             Tb2.Text = session["currentTb2"].toString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hesap = (((sayi1 - ((sayi1 - sayi2) / 2)) * ((sayi1 - sayi2) / 2)) / 40);
        sonuc = (hesap * sayi3) / 100;
        lbl1.Text = sonuc.ToString() + "kg";
        session["currentTb1"] = Tb1.Text;
        session["currentTb2"] = Tb2.Text;
    }


}
```

Comment: ah, I thought you wanted to reload the previous text box value if there was an error.